# nginx proxy_pass to a directory

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

How can I setup nginx to reverse proxy a single folder to one server and the rest of root to a different server?

The root "/" is managed by CMS while the "other" is my own programs (independent of the CMS).

Here is my current configuration

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen   443;
    ... <ssl stuff> ...

    server_name www.example.com;

    location /other {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.2.2/other ;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

reference to nginx docs:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass

You should change the `other` location to this:

```
location /other/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.2.2/other/ ;
}
```

Note the trailing `/`. It actually make a difference since it gets `proxy_pass` to normalize the request. I quote:

> when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the [proxy_pass] directive.

This should help those that find this page.

Comment: Thank you soo much. I needed a way to use nginx as a reverse proxy but wanted the URL to be rewrited/prefixed with a folder. This works like a charm (without the folder in the location part ofcourse)!

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, i was redirect example.com/admin to another nginx in a docker container. Is there a way to remove tail slash at the end of url `example.com/admin/`, it is appended all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
You needs to use this code , i think it work

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen   443;
    ... <ssl stuff> ...

    server_name www.example.com;

    location = /other {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.2.2/other ;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.1.1;
    }
}
```